# Service Cloud | Live Chat functionality

Tags: liveagent

Dear Salesforce lovers,

I have a query regarding Live Chat functionality, I understand that it can handle 3 – 5 simultaneous chats at once so does it mean that many windows can be open at the same time or it is only one window with different tabs?

Thanks for the reply in advance.

Cheers,

Sandrine

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple windows. Quoting the relevant excerpt from the [Live Agent Developer Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/live_agent_dev/live_agent_dev_guide.pdf),

> A deployment consists of a few lines of JavaScript that you add to a
>   Web page. Your organization can have a single Live Agent deployment or
>   multiple deployments. For example, if you have a single service center
>   that supports multiple websites, creating a separate deployment for
>   each site enables you to present multiple chat windows to your
>   visitors. Each deployment includes a chat window, which visitors use
>   to chat with support agents.

Answer (score 0):

From the agent perspective it looks more like one window with multiple tabs. Perhaps, I am not understanding what you mean by windows but a window would actually require opening the console on multiple pages (windows) which is not possible unless you have enabled the recent feature "[Multi-Monitor](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/he-il/spring14/release-notes/console2_multi_monitor_using.htm)" components and even so, it does not open a new chat in a new window for every new chat.

This is what an agent sees when more than one chat is open. As you can see, a new tab is added for every new visitor engaged in a chat with the agent.

[image]

Comment: Thank for your reply coming along with a screenshot. Just to be precised, is it extra tabs from the console or from the chat window itself? Cheers

Comment: The extra tabs are created in the console but every tab contains the chat details and the chat window.

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift reply. This was helpful.

Comment: @SandrineForce I am glad I was able to help. If you think is answers your question, please accept the answer so that other users are able to benefit from it as well :)

Comment: Yes I did it. Let me know if you do not see anything since I am not too familiar with the site yet. Cheers, Sandrine

Comment: @SandrineForce No worries,  to accept an answer you just have to click on the check mark icon next to the original answer. Welcome to SFSE :)